# Computation of sheaf of regular functions over a topological space

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I would like to compute the following sheaf of regular functions over topological space $X\subset A^2$ over $C$ in a systematic manner.

$X$ is endowed with subspace topology of $A^2$. Consider any open set $U\cap X\subset X$. So $U=D(f_1,\dots, f_n)=\cap D(f_i)$. I always have an injective restriction map $O_X(D(f_i))=A(X)_{f_i}\to O_X(U)$ where the former indicates localization at $f_i$. So $\{\frac{g}{\prod_i f_i^{n_i}}\vert g\in A(X)\}\subset O_X(U)$ where the former indicates the subring generated by those elements.

---

Hope I am correct so far. Is this all the elements of $O_X(U)$? How do I conclude that I do not have anything extra? Is there a generic way to construct sheaf of regular functions?

---

I computed $X=V(x_1x_2)$. Open set on $X$ can avoid either only finitely many points, $x_i=0$, $x_i=0$ plus some points or everything.

For open set $U$ avoiding points on $x_1$ axis, $O_X(U)=k[x_1,x_2]_{\{(x_1-a_i)\}}$ where $\{(x_1-a_i)\}$ is simply multiplicative closed set formed by points avoided. If $U$ avoids more points, then $O_X(U)$ is simply localize at more points.

If $U$ avoids $x_i=0$, $O_X(U)=k[x_1,x_2]_{(x_i)}$. If $U$ avoids $x_1=0$ and some extra points on $x_2=0$, $O_X(U)=k[x_1,x_2]_{(x_2,\{x_1-a_i\})}$

---

Correction: All $k[x_1,x_2]$ should quotient out $I(X)$.

Comment: What is $X$ in your first two paragraphs and why $O_X(D(f_i))=A(X)_{f_i}$ and why $O_X(D(f_i))\to O_X(U)$ is injective?

Comment: @chankifung $X$ is some variety in $A^n$ in general for the 2nd paragraph and $X$ is some variety in $A^2$ for the 1st paragraph. I think I can take $X$ as some irreducible variety. $O_X(D(f_i))$ is the sheaf of regular functions on $X$. I would expect $O_X(D(f_i))\to O_X(U)$ for $U=\cup D(f_i)$ injective if $U$ is dense in $X$ which is irreducible. I do not think this holds in general.

Comment: If $X$ is the union of the two axes $V(x_1x_2)$, and $U$ is the complement of $(a,0)$ in $X$, then $O_X(X)=k[x_1,x_2]/<x_1x_2>$ , and $O_X(U)=(k[x_1,x_2]/<x_1x_2>)_{x_1-a} $ instead.

Comment: If $X$ is a quasi-compact, quasi-separated scheme, $f$ is a regular function on $X$, and $X_f$ is the open subscheme of $X$ defined by $f\neq 0$, then $O_X(X_f)=O_X(X)_f$, see Vakil 7.3.5 qcqs lemma.

Comment: @chankifung Yes. I think I forgot to quotient out $I(X)$. Is it true for general open set $O_X(U)=S^{-1}A(X)$ for $S\subset A(X)$ with $\{f_i\}= S$ where $\cup D(f_i)=U$ and $S$ is the multiplicative set generated by $f_i$?

Comment: @chankifung How can one compute $O_X(U)$ for some general open set $U=\cup D(f_i)$?

Comment: I think $O_X(\cup D(f_i))$ is the limit of $O_X(\cup D(f_i))$. In the case $X$ is irreducible, then $O_X(\cup D(f_i))$ is the intersection of $O_X(\cup D(f_i))$ in the function field $K(X)$ of $X$.

Comment: @chankifung I see. Thanks a lot.